# Use of unresolved identifier 'className': Xcode recognises all classes defined in files except one

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, tvos

I have these Swift files. Each one contains a class with a similar name.

[image]
In the file **CMErrorHandler**, I have this code:

```
    if let _ = CMSessionManager.sharedInstance.tokenExpiration {
         sessionExpired = CMSessionManager.sharedInstance.tokenExpiration!.isLessThanDate(dateToCompare: Date())
     }

     let error = CMError(code: errorCode, title: errorTitle, message: errorDescription)
     if error.code == 1160 || error.code == 401 || sessionExpired {
         //Session expired --> Logout
         showAlertAndPop(title: (error.title)!, message: (error.message)!, action: {
             // The code inside the disconnect function has been commented
             //  Check comment inside of function
           
                CMProfileManager.sharedInstance.disconnect()
             })
 //            return
         }
```

The code that uses **CMSessionManager** class works fine:

```
if let _ = CMSessionManager.sharedInstance.tokenExpiration {
         sessionExpired = CMSessionManager.sharedInstance.tokenExpiration!.isLessThanDate(dateToCompare: Date())
     }
```

But, the code that uses `CMProfileManager` throws an error:

```
 CMProfileManager.sharedInstance.disconnect()
```

The error:

> Use of unresolved identifier **CMProfileManager**

I don't understand, why can Xcode find **CMSessionManager** and cannot find **CMProfileManager** if both are defined in the same way and in the same location.

```
class CMProfileManager {
static let sharedInstance = CMProfileManager()
 }
```

Comment: Check the "Target Membership" of the `CMProfileManager.swift` file in the right panel. Is your target checked?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes it is

Comment: @Sweeper For some reason, the error disappeared and Xcode recognises the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean build if does not resolve .. restart your `Xcode`.. Check the "`Target Membership`" of the `CMProfileManager.swift` file in the right panel. Is your target checked